# skip wait for user input *sudo password

Tags: linux, bash, password

i got a problem when my users dont install system with username and password which IT give to them. Some of those people left old password, and i want to solve this while run bash script and put those password inside it.
So idea is:
if oldpassword is entered set it tu newer, and then change as usual new root password.
My problem here is where users put NEWUSERPASSWORD already and this first line can't be skipped, it wait for user input, cause i cant echo wrong password.
Is there a solution for skipping wait for user input?

```
echo olduserpassword | sudo -S echo "user:newuserpassword" | sudo chpasswd  
echo newuserpassword | sudo -S echo "root:betterpassword" | sudo chpasswd
```

i tried to add ; to skip if error, and also tried to add  sudo chpasswd  < /dev/null

Comment: I think you want something like `echo olduserpassword | sudo -S sh -c 'echo "user:newuserpassword" | chpasswd'`